# JQuery for mobile safari: on() fails

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

I'm trying to change some classes on dynamically generated DOM elements for a mobile web page.
My usual method, the jquery `on()` doesn't pick up the events properly.

Neither does `"delegate()"`, my backup work.

I'm using JQuery version "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js"

Comment: The solution was to add onclick='' to the div element. Not sure why that worked, but it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add onclick='' to the div element. Not sure why that worked, but it did. –

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the on, can't you just write the event as it is?

Such as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  });
$(document).click(function () {  });
$(document).keyup(function () {  });
$(document).keydown(function () {  });
```

?

Remember to add the events to the objects once the DOM is loaded. Cause if you try to use a jQuery selector outside a DOM ready check it might execute before the actual element is loaded and then it won't find anything. Which will result in no events happening.

Comment: I think the issue is that if you dynamically generate an element with a different piece of jQuery, then the DOM isn't loaded, which is why people use on(), live(), and delegate().

Comment: Thanks, i guess we all learn something new every day :) Glade you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Live` event as

```
$(".element").live("click",function(){
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

to attach event on dynamically generated DOM elements

Comment: This works in Chrome on my desktop, my android browser, but not in safari on my iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using jQuery 1.7.1 with jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 Final. It's important to be using version 1.7.1 of jQuery, not the 1.7.2 that is available right now as the latest.

Using on() in place of everything provides a much better experience. In fact, almost everything else has been deprecated.

I rambled a bit about this on a blog post a few weeks ago.

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/04/using-new-jquery-1-7-on-off-functions/