# jQuery on() doesn't work with mobile Safari

Tags: jquery, mobile-safari

I want to toggleClass of lists dynamically generated with jQuery $.ajax({...}) with an XML file. It works fine on the desktop with Safari and Chrome but not with mobile Safari. Delegate and Live don't work on mobile either.

I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 iPad (iOS 5.1) iPhone (iOS 5.0.1)
Not using jQuery mobile

jQuery docs recommends using .on() instead of .live() since live is deprecated starting 1.7

oringal html

```
<ul id="movies">
   /* empty */
</ul>
```

after dynamic build

```
<ul id="movies">
    <li>Movie-1</li>
    <li>Movie-2</li>
    <li>Movie-3</li>
</ul>
```

The following works on desktop Safari and Chrome but not on mobile Safari.

```
$(document).on('click', '#movies li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

cyrusv seems to have asked a similar question and answered the solution himself too but he didn't elaborate enough. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9538134/372567
Says:

> add onclick='' to the div element. Not sure why
>   that worked, but it did. –

Comment: cyrusv seems to have asked a similar question and answered the solution himself too but he didn't elaborate enough. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9538134/372567)

Comment: I use jQuery on() for many things in my applications and they all work in iOS Safari for iPhone and iPad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't best practice to bind events to the `document` element, you should do this instead:

```
$('#movies').on('click', 'li', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Also bad practice to specify tagtype with ID. There should only be ONE of an ID. Adding `ul` causes jQuery to loop through the entire DOM looking for DOMS with that ID. Leaving it at `#movies` let's it stop when it finds the first instance

Comment: For classes: just fine. CSS: wonderful. Not so much jQuery and Ids

Comment: Yes, sure :) I typed too fast.

Comment: Thank you Kyle. This was my first time using .on() and didn't understand the problem but now that I see your solution it seems so basic. Thank you, great job!

Comment: Thank you Darius for the answer.

Answer (score 4):

So, just to sum this all up, as it took me hours of debugging/surfing before I arrived here:

To make event bindings persist after Ajax calls, you need to bind them to document not the element, e.g:

INSTEAD OF:

```
$('.foo').on('click', function() { ... }
```

USE:

```
$( document ).on('click', '.foo', function () { ... }
```

BUT this document binding won't work on Safari for iOS mobile, UNLESS you also include `onclick=""` in the element's HTML. Strange but true.

Comment: For anyone else looking: I have run into the issue of Safari for iOS mobile and testing on BrowserStack seems to suggest `onclick="void(0)"` might be more helpful. `onclick=""` did not work by itself. I am not sure if this is a BrowserStack issue or not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue using on(). It worked on the chrome and safari on desktop but didn't work in any mobile browser. The solution, like cyrusv suggested, was to do so:

JQuery:

```
$('#questions').on('click', 'li', function() {
    ....
});
```

Change HTML from:

```
<div id="questions"> 
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="questions"> 
  <li onclick=''>...</li>
  <li onclick=''>...</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you wrapped in a jQ DocReady? `$(function() { ... })`

```
$(function() {
  $('#movies li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with `on('change')`. when i added `onchange=''` to the html it worked.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).on is a problem on new versions of desktop Safari as well (At least 8.0.8). Safari also has a problem with Ajax POST calls using only a variable and not specifying name and value. Only specifying a variable works in both Chrome and Firefox.

Will not work in Safari:

```
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("AjaxAction")",
            data: {
                id
            }
        });
```

Works in all browsers:

```
var id = 1;
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("AjaxAction")",
            data: {
                id:id
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact good practice to delegate to higher elements, either document or other containers. Though when targeting iOS you have to take the following into consideration: **doing event delegation in jQuery like `$(document).on('click', '.target-element', function (event) {...});` will not work**. You have to add either `onclick=""` to the target element or `cursor: pointer` to its styles.

Explanation taken and adapted from http://gravitydept.com/blog/js-click-event-bubbling-on-ios:

> It turns out that Safari on the iPhone does not support event delegation for click events, unless the click takes place on a link or input. Fortunately there are workarounds available.

Answer (score 0):

Two more selectors for the sake of options :)

```
$("#movies li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})

$("ul[id='movies'] li").on("click", function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
})
```